# Instanced Scene not showing up no matter what I do in GODOT4

Tags: c#, game-development, godot, godot4

Here is my code - I have instanced a temporary ballScene as well as the fireballScene which is called when shoot is pressed , however when I run the game and press shoot none of the fireball scenes show up and instead only prints out my "shoot fireball method" statement suggesting the line below does not work. Does anyone know why it doesnt work ?

```cs
    using Godot;
    using System;
    public partial class Player1 : CharacterBody2D
    {
        public PackedScene fireballScene;
        public int ammo = 100;
        public override void _Ready()
        {
            GD.Print("Ready Function works");
            //fireballScene = ResourceLoader.Load<PackedScene>("res://fireball.tscn");
            PackedScene ballScene = (PackedScene)GD.Load("res://fireball.tscn");
            Node newInstance = (Node)ballScene.Instantiate();
            GetTree().CurrentScene.AddChild(newInstance);
    
        }
        public override void physicsprocess{
                if(Input.IsActionPressed("shoot"))
            {
                Vector2 direction = GetGlobalMousePosition() - GlobalPosition;
                shootFireball(direction);
            }
        }
        public void shootFireball(Vector2 direction)
        {
            GD.Print("shoot fireball method");
            PackedScene tempScene = ResourceLoader.Load<PackedScene>("res://fireball.tscn");
                    
                if (tempScene == null)
                {
                    GD.Print("Failed to load the fireball scene.");
                    return;
                }
        
            GD.Print("shoot fireball method");
            fireball fireballInstance = fireballScene.Instantiate() as fireball;
            GD.Print("fireball instanced");
            if (fireballInstance != null)
            {
                GD.Print("fireball not null");
                fireballInstance.Start(GlobalPosition, direction);
                AddChild(fireballInstance);
                ammo--;
            }
            if(fireballInstance == null)
            {
                GD.Print("FIreball scene null");
            }
        }
    
    }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why isnt my spike shooters child showing up in the scene in godot?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77274578/why-isnt-my-spike-shooters-child-showing-up-in-the-scene-in-godot)