# Why is my function not spawning any child nodes?

Tags: nodes, gdscript

```
func shoot():
    const bullet = preload("res://bullet.tscn")
    var new_bullet = bullet.instantiate()
    new_bullet.global_position = %ShootingPoint.global_position
    %ShootingPoint.add_child(new_bullet)
    print("SHOT")

func _process(_delta):
    shoot()
```

I am trying to spawn a bullet at a Marker2D named ShootingPoint.
I added *print("SHOT")* at the end of the shoot function to confirm the code is actually running, and it works fine.

[Debug Log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pMXQi.png)

Ive been using the shooting mechanic from the GDQuest https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GwCiGixlqiU&t=5713s that came out a few days ago.

Running the game with a bullet already spawned it works completely fine, they just wont spawn in.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why isnt my spike shooters child showing up in the scene in godot?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77274578/why-isnt-my-spike-shooters-child-showing-up-in-the-scene-in-godot)