# Godot4 - How can I reference the property of a preloaded scene in the _ready() method of the scene it is preloaded in?

Tags: godot, gdscript, godot4

I am a Godot beginner and currently trying to replicate the famous snake game. In the _ready() method of the snake_manager scene (Code below), I want to set the global_position of the preloaded scene "snake_head_segment" and "snake_body_segment". My problem now is that the global_position property of the snake_head_segment is null when I try to set its position.
I get this error: Invalid set index 'global_position' (on base: 'CharacterBody2D (snake_head.gd)') with value of type 'Nil'.
The code of the snake_manager scene:

```
extends Node

var snake_body_segment: PackedScene = preload("res://scenes/gameobjects/snake_segment/snake_segment.tscn")
var snake_head_segment: PackedScene = preload("res://scenes/gameobjects/snake_head/snake_head.tscn")
var snake_segments_list = [snake_head_segment, snake_body_segment, snake_body_segment]


func _ready():
    var body_part
    for x in range(0, len(snake_segments_list)):
        body_part = snake_segments_list[x].instantiate()
        snake_segments_list[x] = body_part
        get_parent().add_child.call_deferred(body_part)
        snake_segments_list[x].global_position = get_segment_position(snake_segments_list, x)


func _process(_delta):
    for x in range (1, len(snake_segments_list)):
        var tween = get_tree().create_tween()
        tween.tween_property(snake_segments_list[x], "position", get_segment_position(snake_segments_list, x), .5)


func get_segment_position(snake_segments, x):
        if snake_segments[0].velocity.x != 0:
            if snake_segments[0].velocity.normalized() == Vector2.RIGHT:
                return Vector2(snake_segments[x - 1].global_position.x - 40, snake_segments[x - 1].global_position.y)
            elif snake_segments[0].velocity.normalized() == Vector2.LEFT:
                return Vector2(snake_segments[x - 1].global_position.x + 40, snake_segments[x - 1].global_position.y)
        elif snake_segments[0].velocity.y != 0:
            if snake_segments[0].velocity.normalized() == Vector2.DOWN:
                return Vector2(snake_segments[x - 1].global_position.x, snake_segments[x - 1].global_position.y - 40)
            elif snake_segments[0].velocity.normalized() == Vector2.UP:
                return Vector2(snake_segments[x - 1].global_position.x, snake_segments[x - 1].global_position.y + 40)
```

I would really appreciate your help and thank you in advance.

Kind regards,
Gabriel

I checked with breakpoints which _ready() method is called first and found out that the _ready() method of the snake_manager (the parent node) is called before the _ready() method of the snake_head_segment scene (child node).That's probably the reason for the error.

Comment: i think you need to reference the root node in the scene for positions rather than the scene itself -> so instead of `snake_segments_list[x].global_position`, use `snake_segements_list[x].get_root().global_position`

Comment: Hi Niro, thank you very much for your response. Unfortunately that didn't fix my problem. I changed the code as you said and now become the error: Invalid call. Nonexistent function 'get_root' in base 'CharacterBody2D(snake_head.gd)'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is riddled with issues.

First I need to point out tha the type of elements of `snake_segments_list` changes from `PackedScene` to `CharacterBody2D`. This not make it easier to reason about the code.

---

While reading the code the first potential problem I saw was that you would be setting `global_position` before `add_child` gets to run. See my answer to the question [Why isnt my spike shooters child showing up in the scene in godot?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77277265/402022) to find out why that might be an issue.

However, that is a potentially unexpected behavior, and the execution is not even getting there...

---

The next thing I noticed is the following...

You are making a loop where `x` will be in the range from `0` to the size of `snake_segments`. On each iteration you are calling `get_segment_position` passing `x`.

This means that the first time you call it, `x` will be `0`. And so the lines where you access `snake_segments[x - 1]` are reading the index `-1`.

In Godot, reading the `-1` index of an `Array` will give you the last item of the `Array`. However, the loop has not ran for the last item, so it has not been instantiated.

In fact, the last item would be a `PackedScene`, (although you expect it to be `CharacterBody2D`. And no, `PackedScene` does not have a `global_position` property.

...But this isn't the error either. Because the execution code is not even getting to the point to try to read the `global_position` of a `PackedScene`, because the the first element of `snake_segments` (i.e. the head) has zero `velocity`.

---

And that brings us to the problem at hand: When the head has zero `velocity` `get_segment_position` does not return.

Thus in this line:

```
snake_segments_list[x].global_position = get_segment_position(snake_segments_list, x)
```

It acts as a `null`, and you can't set a null to the `global_position` of a `CharacterBody2d`. You have to set a `Vector2`. Hence the error.

If you had declared the return value of `get_segment_position`, Godot would have pointed out that it didn't always return.

---

Right, let us talk about fixing it. Presumably if the `velocity` of the head is zero, you don't want the `global_position` of the segments to change, so you can add a line at the end of `get_segment_position` to return the current `global_position` of the segment.

Comment: Hi Theraot, thank you very much for your detailed explanation of the error. Now everything works fine. I really appreciate it :)